# Setting Linux UID on NFS volume from EMC NX4

Tags: nfs, cifs, emc

I have an EMC NX4 from which there are several CIFS shares with corresponding NFS mount points. The CIFS user ids seem fine but when viewed from Linux they are all 327xx numbers and can't be set from the file system. (IE CHOWN doesn't work - permission denied).

On our other (older) EMC devices we used an MMC app to set the Linux UID for each user. I don't seem to have such an app on the 'Applications and Tools' CD for this new device. Is there some other method for setting these? Did I setup the system incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the usermapper service on the datamover is not enabled or not running.   If you have powerlink access you can review this document:

[PowerLink UserMapper Guide](https://powerlink.emc.com/nsepn/webapps/btg548664833igtcuup4826/km/live1/en_US/Offering_Technical/Technical_Documentation/300-011-856.pdf?mtcs=ZXZlbnRUeXBlPUttQ2xpY2tTZWFyY2hSZXN1bHRzRXZlbnQsZG9jdW1lbnRJZD0wOTAxNDA2NjgwNTg4MWEyLGRhdGFTb3VyY2U9RENUTV9lbl9VU18w)

The MMC Snap in is on the Applications CD, if you can't find it you can always download it from PowerLink also, but you'll need to open a support session via Chat to get the link.  It's not "publicly available" for some reason...

Comment: Is the NX4 a VNX device? Im still foggy about the various EMC product lines.

Comment: Actually no, the NX4 is based on the CX4 series, but the NAS head is IDENTICAL, with the exception of the version number in the OS.  No major software changes from Nas code 6 to 7.